# Linguagem C: Manipulando um vetor de structs dentro de funções

Tags: c, struct, array, passagem-por-referência

Olá,
Criei um `struct`:

```
typedef struct 
    {
        float valor;
        float peso;
    } objeto;
```

*E dentro da main() eu crei um vetor desses caras:*

```
objeto conjunto[50];
```

*Aí, eu preciso trocar um 'objeto' de lugar com outro dentro do vetor:*

```
void ordena(objeto conjunto[],int n)
{
    int i, maior = conjunto[n].valor;
    for ( ; n > 1; n-- )
    {
        maior = selecMaior(conjunto, n );
        if (  conjunto[maior].valor > conjunto[n].valor )
            troca( &conjunto[n], &conjunto[maior]);
    }
}
void troca(objeto *a, objeto *b)
{
    objeto aux;
    aux.valor = a->valor;  
    aux.peso = a->peso;

    a->valor = b->valor;
    a->peso = b->valor;

    b->valor = aux.valor;
    b->peso = aux.peso;
}
```

Só que o Dev++ está resmungando:

***( no cabeçalho do troca() )***

> [Warning] conflicting types for 'troca'

***( na linha da chamada )***

> [Note] previous implicit declaration of 'troca' was here

*Conforme o material que consultei estaria certo, e também já peguei um código assim funcionando. Onde eu tô errando*

Comment: Coloque todo seu código para que dê para ver,os o problema. [mcve]

Comment: Troque de lugar (posição) as funções ordena e troca (troca vem primeiro)

Comment: Obrigado pela edição, farei dessa forma nas minhas próximas dúvidas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é só que o compilador chega na chamada a função "troca" em sua função "main" antes de "ver" a declaração de "troca" - então assume que é uma função que retorna um `int` (o padrão em C), e simplesmente põe os parâmetros na chamada, sem ter a menor idéia se estão corretos ou não.

A forma de resolver isso é declarar a função "troca" no início do arquivo, antes da função `main` - não necessariamente movendo o corpo da função para lá - C permite o uso de "prototypes"  (protótipos) que são exatamente  identicos à declaração da função, mas terminados com um `;`, em vez de uma `{` que iniciaria a função em si.

Assim, no seu arquivo, você colocaria:

```
void troca(objeto *a, objeto *b);
...

void ordena(...) {
...
}
...
void troca(objeto *a, objeto *b) {
...}
```

E fica tudo bem.
Em geral, os prototypes são colocados nos arquivos `.h` em programas maiores em C - além de permitirem o acesso às funções independente da ordem em que foram declarados, são a forma de permitir o uso de funções que estão em outros arquivos `.c` no seu sistema, ou mesmo em bibliotecas à parte:  na verdade, eles são a principal razão de ser necessário incluir os arquivos ".h" - quando alguém digita `#include <stdio.h>` - o stdio.h não tem o cóidigo das funções printf, scanf, etc... O que ele tem são os prototypes - aí o compilador sabe como montar as chamadas para essas funções, e num passo seguinte, de ligação do objeto, que pode ser em tempo de execução, é que o código dessas funções é executado: o cóidgo em C das mesmas nem precisa estar presente no computador em que você compila o programa.

Num ambiente em que você está compilando um software complexo, por exemplo, para manipular imagens do tipo "jpg" - o seu computador precisa ter a "libjpeg" instalada - só os binários =  mas para compilar o seu progama você precisa ter os arquivos ".h" daquela biblioteca. é por isso, por xemplo, que em várias distribuições Linux existem em pacotes separados uma biblioteca (por exemplo, "libjpeg") - que só contém o código já compilado daquela biblioteca, os arquivos de desenvolvimento daquela biblioteca (ex.: "libjpeg-dev") - que contém os arquivos ".h" com os prototypes das funções públicas, e o código fonte da biblioteca (ex. "libjpeg-src").  Qualquerum que só vá isntalar programas já compilados, só precisa do primeiro. Quem vai compilar programas (seus ou de terceiros) que vão manipular arquivos JPEG, precisa dos dois primeiro - e só precisa do código fotne completo quem quer estudar como a biblioteca funciona por dentro, ou procurar a fotne de algum bug relcionado à mesma.  (Quem quer contribuir com o desenvolviemento da biblioteca, aí já pega a biblioteca do repositório de versionamento dela, não o pacote de uma distribuição específica).

Comment: Obrigado! Antes da sua explicação eu não fazia ideia do porquê de alguns códigos terem esses tais prototypes.

Comment: Legal - complementei um pouco mais a resposta - dê uma lida.